# angular js - code flow based on device orientation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Having some trouble visualizing how to structure my browser based web app to have different behavior based on screen size and orientation.  My app is built on angular and ui-router for my states, and bootstrap for my styles.  Current functionality is the same on both phones and tables.  It's basically:

- Show list of items
- Click on list item
- go to detail state

However, if a user is using tablet I want the following functionality (based on orientation):

**Portrait**

- Same as above

**Landscape**

- List of items floats all the way left
- detail view becomes viewable to the right (IE any email app you've ever used on a tablet)
- clicking on a list item populates the detail view to the right.

I guess I'm struggling with how to set that up with angular. Right now, clicking an item changes the state entierly (which re-renders the view).  Would I just need to do something like this when clicking an item (sudo code):

```
if (orientation === "portait" && tablet) {
    $state.go("detailview");
} else if (orientation === "landscape" && tablet) {
    $scope.details = getTheDeets();
}
```

And then use media queries in my list view to hide / show the details section based on screen size and orientation?

Open and appreciative of any suggestions regarding how one might set this up.  Thanks!

Comment: You can have multiple views with ui-router. Have the detail assigned to the second view. Then use a css media query to hide it in desktop. This isn't very ideal because it would take resources to process that view when it isn't being used. Might not be a big problem for your app though.

Comment: Ah, you're on to something there.  I wonder if I could use that in conjunction with ng-if to not process if we're not in landscape for example.  At any rate, that gives me some ideas.  Thanks @JamesKleeh!

Comment: You could use a custom directive in conjunction with ng-if to update the ng-if variable. The custom directive could watch the display property of the element and set the ng-if variable to true if its hidden. You could probably `require: '^ngIf'`, however I've never tried that. Really IMO whether the app is in landscape or what device is using it should not be a part of the JS at all.

Comment: @JamesKleeh so you're suggesting that I shouldn't be using states to show views in this case?  Just make it so there is only one page that shows both list and details, and use media queries to handle which is displayed and when?  That's might not be a bad idea either.

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed a nice question, Don't know the exact solution for it, but a way around is by using the screen width:

```
var screenWidth   = window.innerWidth;
```

For iPad 1, you get it as:

```
portait    =  768
landscape  =  1024
```

For iPhone4, you get it as:

```
portait    =  640
landscape  =  960
```

Similarly, you can check the screen width for your target device.

**Note:**
This implementation can be followed only on first loading, but it won't play any role once first loading is done and you changed the orientation.

Another way around is using:
 `@media (min-width:641px) {}`
i Don't have much idea and need to look up.